# How to replay the moves in a Chess.app game?

Tags: games

I have saved games in `Chess.app` for which I want to see a replay. A saved game is a plaintext XML file, e.g. for the [Alekhine defence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alekhine%27s_Defence):

```
<key>Moves</key>
<string>e2e4
g8f6
...
```

[This thread](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/mac-chess-replay-game-or-moves.1964066/) with a similar question has no answers. How can I replay the moves?